# Clear certain cells on Window Close AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted an appscript mechanism, where I want to clear certain cells (A2:B8) if the spreadsheet window is closed. I have one way of doing it and that is:

```
onOpen()
{
  sheet.getRange("A2:B8").setValues("");
}
```

But this seems like a hack but I wanted to know if there's a definite way to do so... like for example:

`Browser.onWindowClose()=>{clearCells()}`

Answer (score 5):

You maybe able to do this if you have a modal dialog or sidebar open. If sidebar or dialog  close is attempted, you may be able to catch the event with [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event), if catched, clear all cells using [`google.script.run()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). This assumes user is closing the sidebar before/along with the  Google sheets main web app.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't `onClose()` or `onExit()` built in trigger as of yet.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) is the list with all the currently available triggers.

The lack of this feature has already been reported in the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757543).
You can go there and click on the **star** button to the top left of the page to "increase" the chances for this feature to be implemented by google.

As a side note, [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) would be more appropriate:

```
sheet.getRange("A2:B8").clearContent();
```